# MYSQL multi JOIN from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have multiple MYSQLI tables for multiple details and options about a touristic package. 
I have *package* containing the main information, then I have *package_option* which contains unknown number of options added to the package, and there's *package_images* which contains the images.

I want to get all the information in one query, but it's prooving a difficult task. Let me explain.

I've used JOIN with but the problem was if the *package_option* had 3 options and the *package_images* had 6 images, the result was a 6*4 plus 1 (*package*) result table.

I would like a result containing all the fields, as many as they originaly are in the tables, not multiplied for each match in every table.

For example, the table I aim for looks like that:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | name | description | price | option | image | size | explanation |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | test | some desc   | 50 $  | opt. 1 | img1  |  30  |             |
|    |      |             |       | opt. 2 | img2  |      |             |
|    |      |             |       | opt. 3 | img3  |      |             |
|    |      |             |       |        | img4  |      |             |
|    |      |             |       |        | img5  |      |             |
|    |      |             |       |        | img6  |      |             |
```

Right now, the above table gets populated in every field, but it's multiplied, so I don't get only 6 rows, but 24.

I did a lot of JOINS, I'm not a beginer, which is even more frustrating, but it's the first time I try to do that, a select from multiple tables with different columns and unknown number of rows.

*package_option* and *package_images* looks like that:

```
-------------------------------------
| ID  | package_id | option / image |
-------------------------------------
| 1   | 1          | opt. 1 / img 1 |
| 2   | 2          | opt. 2 / img 2 |
..... etc
```

so I don't know how many rows I'll have.

Thank you in advance for t

Comment: Use `group_concat` and group the results. `select ID, group_concat(option),  group_concat(image), other columns from table group by ID`.

Comment: It worked, but in a strange way, I now have all the images names as string, separated by comma, they are not one in each row. But, there's the query, maybe I'm doing it wrong:

SELECT pachete.*, GROUP_CONCAT(pachete_optiuni.optiune) AS packOpt, GROUP_CONCAT(pachete_imagini.imagine) AS packImg, GROUP_CONCAT(pachete_imagini.ordine) AS packImgOrd
FROM pachete
INNER JOIN pachete_optiuni ON pachete_optiuni.id_pachet=pachete.id
INNER JOIN pachete_imagini ON pachete_imagini.id_pachet=pachete.id
WHERE pachete.id=43

Comment: Yea, it puts them all as one column per row. What did you want? You can change the `,` to a `/` to match your question; `GROUP_CONCAT(pachete_imagini.imagine SEPARATOR ' / ')`.

Comment: I appologize, I now realise I might've confused everybody with the question. I need a result like the first table I drew. Each picture and option in it's own row.

Comment: Doesn't the original query do that? I'm lost.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139851/discussion-between-lucian-minea-and-chris85).